# Strange issue with Vertx Http request

Tags: httpclient, vert.x

I configured an HTTPS website on AWS, which allows visiting from a white list of IPs.
My local machine runs with a VPN connection, which is in the white list.
I could visit the website from web browser or by the java.net.http package with the below code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("https://mywebsite/route"))
    .GET() // GET is default
    .build();
HttpResponse<Void> response = client.send(request,
    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding());
```

But if I replaced the code with a Vertx implementation from io.vertx.ext.web.client package, I got a 403 forbidden response from the same website.

```
WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true).setTrustAll(true);
HttpRequest<Buffer> request = WebClient.create(vertx, options)
            .getAbs("https://mywebsite/route")
            .ssl(true).putHeaders(headers);
request.send(asyncResult -> {
      if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            HttpResponse response = asyncResult.result();
      }
});
```

Does anyone have an idea why the Vertx implementation is rejected?

Comment: maybe you need to add the port: `.getAbs("https://mywebsite:443/route")`

Comment: I tried but still no luck :(

Comment: The snippet with Vert.x shows `headers` to be sent while the other snippet doesn't. Is there any authentication check that is denied because the values provided in headers are wrong?

Comment: Just had a new finding. Vertx implementation sent the request with host=localhost:443 while the Java.net implementation just package mywebsite:443 as the host. Then localhost is blocked by the AWS firewall. So the next step is, to find why Vertx package the request with host=localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the root cause. I started a local server that accepts the testing request and forwards it to the server on AWS. The testing client sent the request to localhost and thus "Host=localhost:8080/..." is in the request header. In the Vert.X implementation, a new header entry "Host=localhost:443/..." is wrongly put into the request headers. I haven't debug the Vert.X implementation so I have no idea why it behaviors as this. But then the AWS firewall rejected the request with a rule that a request could not come from localhost.